# Why did Annie "Female Titan" stop running?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In *Attack on Titan* season 1 episode 24, Annie "Female Titan" stopped running & was looking at the wall or maybe something else I'm not sure. It seemed that she waited for Eren to punch her & that does not make sense at all.

If she kept running, she could have reached the wall & returned to her "hometown".

So, why did she freeze and stop running?

Comment: I would guess she sensed titans in the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your talking about the part where she was running from the corps and Eren was trapped right? Do remember that Eren had just transformed right as she had stopped moving.

I don't think she stopped moving cause she sense the titans in the wall(that is a bit strange as that reveal was waaay later down the line). I think she stopped casue she realized Eren transformed and might have figured she could flee and takedown Eren at the same time. Or that if she managed to flee, he would follow and hinder her escape outside the city.